# How to print dynamic text in AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, printing

I have a flash application which users enter their name, their ID, and Supervisor name at the beginning. They then watch a clip, and complete a 10 question quiz. At the end a certificate is displayed.

I was able to add all the movie clips (header, logo, etc)to a single clip, and I am able to get it to print (I am trying to figure out how to resize size it smaller, and page orientation landscape next, but that's another question), but I cannot figure out how to get the Name, ID, and Supervisor dynamic text fields to print.

Keep in mind, I have only been doing this for about a week, and have spent 2 days trying to figure this single part out. I think I need to "Draw" these boxes, or add them to a sprite? but I have not a clue. Please help. Thank you

The textbox's I need to add to print are

```
nameout_txt
idout_txt
supervisorout_txt
the_date_txt
```

code:

```
stop();

import flash.printing.PrintJob;


nameout_txt.text = names;
idout_txt.text = id;
supervisorout_txt.text = supervisor;

//Array to hold a list of the weekdays.
var weekdays:Array = new Array ("Sunday","Monday","Tuesday","Wednesday",
"Thursday","Friday","Saturday");

//Array to hold a list of the months.
var months:Array = new Array ("Jan","Feb","Mar","Apr","May","Jun","Jul",
"Aug", "Sep", "Oct","Nov","Dec");

//Adds an event listener to the dymanic text field.
the_date_txt.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,showDate);

function showDate(event:Event):void {
//Create a new instance of the date class.
var myDate:Date = new Date();

//Retrieve the day, month and year from the date class.
var theDay=weekdays[myDate.getDay()];
var theMonth=months[myDate.getMonth()];
var theDate=myDate.getDate();
var theYear=myDate.getFullYear();

//Display the date in the dynamic text field.
the_date_txt.text=theDay+", "+theMonth+" "+theDate+", "+theYear;
}

/* Printing... */

/* Button */
print_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onPrintClick);

function onPrintClick(event:Event):void{

var mySprite:Sprite = new Sprite(); 
var myOptions:PrintJobOptions = new PrintJobOptions(); 
var pj:PrintJob = new PrintJob();
pj.start();
pj.addPage(bgcert_mc);
pj.send();

}
```

Comment: Please do **not** insert 4 spaces to create paragraphs. 4 spaces will format the text as code. Thanks

Comment: This was my first post, I saw how jacked up it looked soon as it posted, thank you for fixing it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know how, and I don't know why, but this code now works. I know for a fact I tried "this" before and it didn't work...now it does.. now on to orientation and maybe size lol

```
/* Printing... */

/* Button */
print_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onPrintClick);

function onPrintClick(event:Event):void{

var mySprite:Sprite = new Sprite(); 
var myOptions:PrintJobOptions = new PrintJobOptions(); 
var pj:PrintJob = new PrintJob();
pj.start();
pj.addPage(this);
pj.send();

}
```